# Seam Framework Clustering: Login state NOT replicating (Seam 2.2.2 + Tomcat 6.0.32)

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat6, cluster-computing, seam2

I am currently trying to make an application written from scratch to be deployable on a Tomcat 6.0.32 cluster, with session/state replication.

Everything works fine except for one thing: if one node of the cluster fails and a request is being redirected to another node, I am no longer logged in. After I log back in, the state of the Session and Conversation scoped beans is restored, so replication basically works except for the login part.

I have tried everything and I really ran out of ideas. Can someone please give me a hint ?

My configuration is as follows: Apache HTTPD and modjk, Apache Tomcat 6.0.32 ,Seam 2.2.2.Final

I have marked the application distributable in web.xml with:

```
<distributable />
```

In components.xml:

```
...
<core:init debug="false" distributable="true" />
...
<security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}" />
...
```

The authenticator class (basically you can login without user/pass at the moment):

```
@Name("authenticator")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
public class ResidentAuthenticator implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4655419361907742527L;

    public boolean authenticate() {

        return true;
    }
}
```

So, does anybody have an idea? Thanks !